# SQL set date_out automatically if today ends

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a visitor system. when the visitor checks in, it sets a date_in. and when the visitor checks out it sets a date_out.

but if a visitor forget to check out. it says he has no date_out so I try to figure out how to set the date_out if the visitor didn't check out.

an example:

Check in: 2015-01-19 12:00:00
visitor forget to check out that day.
so if date is: 2015-01-19 23:59:59. I want it to set it automatically on the date_out.

because with another query I ask all the visitor without a date_out to show. so I can see who is in the building that day.

is there any way to do this automatically?

Table structure

[image: Table structure]

date_in is set when the visitor checks in with his name.

Comment: If you meant to schedule the query for execution then This might help you http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/50237/how-to-automatically-execute-a-stored-procedure-every-day-at-a-particular-time

Comment: Wouldn't merely checking for a null date_out and a date_in for (some point) today return the same result?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever you mean that I adjust my query to check if the date_in is today for showing who is in the building on current date ?

Comment: @GordonLinoff editted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion - rather than editing the data (and subsequently not being able to identify genuine check-outs at 23:59), just update the query:

```
SELECT * /* TODO - actual columns */
FROM visits
WHERE
    date_out IS NULL AND
    date_in >= DATEADD(day,DATEDIFF(day,0,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),0)
```

Where the expression `DATEADD(day,DATEDIFF(day,0,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),0)` is just a way of saying "midnight at the start of today".

The above query should give you the same results as what you're asking for, but leave the actual recorded data intact. That is, only people who've entered today but not left are reported.

The reason I'd recommend not changing the recorded data is in case you decide to change the rules later - i.e. using a different interval than one day to consider a visitor to have left.

Comment: this worked perfectly :). you helped me a lot with this. i had the same thaught but I couldn't figure out any query to do this. and youre query is working. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could create a job that runs 23:59:59 every day that fills the date_out with data.

Comment: I'm not certain if this would necessarily be a good idea.  I suppose that really depends if it's possible for a person to be there for more than one day or not.  If it is, there's no good way to automate this, if not, this would work fine.

Comment: I guess you're running mssql-server so go to: you database object -> SQL server agent -> Jobs -> New Job. Go to schedules to set up when the job is going to run. And set up a step to tell it what to do when it runs.

Comment: as @user2366842 said, it's better to have a keyword to tell the administrators that the visitor never checked out.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the data in a single row, you can just update the values periodically:

```
update visitors
    set check_out = cast(convert(varchar(10), date_in, 121) + ' 23:59:59') as datetime)
    where check_out is null;
```

This can be done at your leisure, rather than guaranteeing that some job run at a specific time.